# Google Data Studio visualize data by frequency of the value

Tags: firebase-analytics, looker-studio

I have a very simple quiz like app which is basically a question and answer. I want to common mistakes of the user i.e. on which question user is making mistake most of the time. For that I have custom event which logs an event every-time a user answers a question wrong. So if there are 5 questions and user usually answers question 3 wrong than the common mistake for that user is question 3.

But in data studio I am not able to find any formula which gets the number of frequency of event value from the big query data-sets. I am looking for a way to implement this any help would be appreciated.

I am using firebase custom events which is linked to bigquery.

Comment: In Data Studio you can also set your source as BigQuery query, so you can do prefiltering and preprocessing with query and then just display data in Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the output of the table to show the Questions on the left, Frequency on the right?

Or you want the output of the table to show the Users on the left, Questions (common mistakes) on the right?

For the first type, **create a table**, set **Question** as *dimension*, **Record Counts** as a *metric*.
For the second type, you can **create a pivot table**. set **User** as *row*, **Questions** as *column*, **Record Counts** as the *metric*